# Cannot launch terminal text editor from Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, vim

I want to edit text in Vim and want to automate the process.
Here's my program:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/example-script
echo "Some Text" > ~/Desktop/filename 
nvim ~/Desktop/filename
```

The program works as required from the terminal. The file is created and I can edit it from vim.

```
$ example-script
$ cat ~/Desktop/filename
This text was edited from Vim
```

However, when launching the program from a keyboard shortcut, Vim is not opened.

Part of the script must have been executed, because the file is reset after executing the shortcut:

```
$ cat ~/Desktop/filename
Some Text
```

[image: Set Custom Shortcut Screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a program that runs in a terminal. Running a terminal command from a keyboard shortcut instead of the terminal emulator will not fire the latter up. Instead, the launched instance of `vim` is sitting somewhere in your computer memory, waiting on input that will never come.

Change your script to read `gnome-terminal -- nvim ~/Desktop/filename` (if you use another terminal emulator, substitute the correct syntax for it). That way, the script will open your terminal with vim automatically opened. When you quit vim, the terminal emulator will directly close.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/akiyosi/goneovim) is a Neovim with a GUI, that runs without a terminal ...

Here you should be able to start it with a shortcut .. haven't tried it, though ....

There is also an interesting discussion on neovim [discourse](https://neovim.discourse.group/t/a-standard-gui/2243/7) about GUIs