# Lubuntu 20.04 executing shell script in terminal from file manager

Tags: scripts, lubuntu, pcmanfm

Lubuntu 20.04, I've got a simple .sh script which I want to execute in a terminal window when double-clicking on it in the file manager (PCManFM-Qt) without confirming my action in the prompt each time.

There is an option in the preferences of PCManFM-Qt to 'Launch executable files without prompt', but then, at least in my case, the default action is just to execute a script, although I'd like to execute this script in a terminal (to see it's output). Although, for some of my other scripts, the default action could be an execution without showing a terminal, so I'd like to configure each of my scripts, whether I want a terminal or not (so it should be not some general system setting).

Comment: I don't know if `pcmanfm-qt` can do that (ie. different rules for specific scripts) so I'd likely have your scripts decide what happens ie. have some of the scripts intentionally hide output (run in background or send output to null) & have them all display output within `pcmanfm-qt` (but the scripts themselves will have no output to display).  The drawback to this is you'll have to 'close' all (ie. all will show a terminal; though if that annoyed me I'd next likely have the script kill itself at the end so it auto-closes - ie. hacks).... I can't think of an elegant solution sorry.

Comment: I just noted you've tagged `pcmanfm` (a different program to `pcmanfm-qt` though by the same developer PCman... I've assumed `pcmanfm-qt` as per your description)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot launch vim from Keyboard Shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331347/cannot-launch-vim-from-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: Thank you guys! Yes I though something about openining a terminal in a script when needed and passing something I need to execute into it as a solution. But it seems the default Lubuntu 20.04 terminal emulator (QTerminal v. 0.14.1) is not accepting any parameters (or at least I didn't find any documentation how to do it). Could you, please, suggest any other terminal emulator which will work on Lubuntu 20.02 and mediocre hardware and solve my problem? Or just tell me how to use QTerminal properly?

Comment: I don't understand your reference to `qterminal` and parameters; but any terminal emulator will work in Lubuntu/LXQt though they may not be as efficient...  a quick look at `konsole` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/konsole) shows whilst it uses the same Qt5 as LXQt does, as LXQt doesn't use KF5 but `konsole` requires it that will use resources (esp. RAM),... but as scripts are run usually by `bash` or other shell, I don't see the connection between terminal & shell sorry.  (there is no Lubuntu 20.02 (2020-February) with releases in April (20.04) & October (20.10) only)

Comment: note: in last comment I used `konsole` as example only... you can run `gnome-terminal` or any other terminal too, each with different resources-hits; I though `konsole` made sense as it least it was a Qt5 based terminal so at least shares some resources with the desktop...

Comment: Sorry for me being not so specific. So what I think could be my solution. In case I need to run my script in terminal when double-clicking it in the file manager, the script I imagine could be something: 
```#!/bin/bash
QTerminal -[some switches] [my command to execute]```

But I don't know which are switches and overall syntax of doing this in QTerminal

Answer (score 1):

As one of possible solutions it could be:

1. Set "Launch executable files without prompt" in PCManFM-Qt to execute scripts without prompt
2. Add execution of script commands via terminal when needed in your scripts, so .sh script could be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
qterminal -e "java -jar your.jar"
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
qterminal -e "your_script.sh"
```